# Make list comprehension of this for loop, Python

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm matching first value of a pair in tuples, and returning the second value if the first value matches across tuples. The code I wrote is working but I want to make it more pythonic, this code looks overly long:

```
  def intersect(A, B):
    setx = set()
    for i in A:
        i, y = i[0], i[1]
        for x in B:
            if i in x:
                x = x[1]
                setx.add((y,x))
    print(setx)
    return setx
```

Now I execute function in interpreter and get the result I want:

```
intersect(
  { (8, 'huit'),
    (10, 'dixA'),
    (12, 'douze')},
  { (5, 'cinq'),
    (10, 'dixB'),
    (15, 'quinze')})
```

and the output shows:

```
{('dixA', 'dixB')}
```

I try to get fancy and try to clean up the code:

```
def intersect(A, B):
    setx = set()
    for i in A:
        i, y = i[0], i[1]
        c = x for x in B if i in x
        #x = c[1]
        setx.add((y,x))
        print(setx)
    return setx
```

The above code gives me an invalid syntax error. When I create a list comprehension

```
[x[1] for x in B if i in x]
```

It returns a list and I cant add lists using the add method of set. Would someone be able to help me clean up my code a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly this worked, I haven't used the double ++ sign in a while:

```
def intersect(A, B):
    setx = set()
    for i in A:
        for x in B:
            if i[0] == x[0]:
                setx.add(i[1]), setx.add(x[1])
    return setx
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.